# How to copy files from remote computer and storing them in local one using WMI and Python?

Tags: python, wmi

I'm new to WMI(Windows management instrumentation) and trying to get files from a remote host.Seeing the wmi docs it says that WMI allows copying files, but never saw an example of it.

Comment: Voting to close because it's to broad and show's no lack of attempt of solving it. [here](https://www.fortynorthsecurity.com/copying-files-via-wmi-and-powershell/)'s information, [here](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/copying-files-using-wmi-48373.html) and [here](https://trevorsullivan.net/2016/10/20/use-powershell-copy-files-wmi/). There's also very well (and good) documentation in microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-tasks--files-and-folders). The **VB** code can be translated using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about WMI but you can serve your files from remote host with python using simply:

python2

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

or python3

`python3 -m http.server`